# Convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{(a_1+\ldots+a_n)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume that $0 < a_n \leq 1$ and that $\sum a_n=\infty$. Is it true that 
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{(a_1+\ldots+a_n)^2} < \infty $$
?

I think it is but I can't prove it. Of course if $a_n \geq \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ this is obvious.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall how do you prove $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: Nice. Added benefit that $\sum a_n = \infty$ isn't necessary (which is obvious on hindsight).

Comment: I don't get this hint

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much. Norbert : remark that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}^2}\leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_n b_{n+1}}$

Comment: @timofei May be i'm stupid but so what then?

Comment: @Norbert, in this case $b_{n+1} - b_n = a_{n+1}$, so RHS in timofei's comment is $\frac{1}{b_n} - \frac{1}{b_{n+1}}$.

Comment: (-1) Bad hint. For those who do not know that trick it doesn't help at all. This is timofei's luck that he unerstood the hint.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Sorry for being dense, but why does $\sum a_n=\infty$ isn't necessary? Don't we need the sum to go to infinity in order for the "telescoping" to succeed?

Comment: @Prism The 'on hindsight' part is that: if $\sum a_n < N$, then $\sum \frac{ a_n} {(a_1 + \ldots + a_n)^2} < \sum \frac { \sum a_n} { a_1 ^2 } < \frac { N } { a_1 ^2 } $. Note that the telescoping (say by Robjohn) still works regardless of the value of $\sum a_n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks! Very good observation.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_n$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{A_n-A_{n-1}}{A_n^2}
&\le\frac1{a_1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{A_n-A_{n-1}}{A_nA_{n-1}}\\
&=\frac1{a_1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{A_{n-1}}-\frac1{A_n}\right)\\
&\le\frac2{a_1}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

There is mre general fact. Assume $a_k\geq 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$
and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges then for all $\delta>0$ the series
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{S_n^{1+\delta}}\tag{1}
$$
converges. Here we denoted $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ Lets apply to the function $f(t)=t^{-\delta}$  Lagrange's mean value theorem on the interval $[S_{n-1},S_n]$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{S_n^\delta}-\frac{1}{S_{n-1}^\delta}=-\frac{\delta}{\xi_n^{1+\delta}}(S_n-S_{n-1})=-\frac{\delta}{\xi_n^{1+\delta}}a_n
$$
for some $\xi_n\in[S_{n-1}, S_n]$. In this case
$$
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a_n}{S_n^{1+\delta}}\leq
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a_n}{\xi_n^{1+\delta}}=
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\delta}\left(\frac{1}{S_{n-1}^\delta}-\frac{1}{S_n^\delta}\right)=\frac{1}{\delta}\left(\frac{1}{S_1^\delta}-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{S_n^\delta}\right)=\frac{1}{\delta}
$$
Hence the series $(1)$ converges.

Comment: You have an extra $\sum a_n/S_n^{1+\delta}$ in a wrong place. But +1.

Comment: @julien, thank you! Now fixed.

Comment: Thank your Norbert. This proof is more general and less "tricky" indeed.